# Expandable div that's rotated with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page layout with a rectangular div on the left side that's rotated 10 degrees, expands with the size of the browser, and doesn't show its edge on the top, left, and bottom. Meaning, the page should appear to be split in the middle on a slant.

My code so far creates the div properly, but when I expand the page you begin to see the edges.

http://jsfiddle.net/jpQvL/1/

HTML

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="right"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
 }

#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
   }    

#right {
    background: #000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 110%;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    top: -73px;
}
```

Comment: Might want to create a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something similar so we can visually see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `tranform` property needs render prefixes. You have to add these lines:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
-o-transform: rotate(10deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
transform: rotate(10deg);
```

[take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/ldaniell14260/akf9d/)

or use one of many prefix-free scripts like [this one](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/)

Comment: Thank you - but my question is how do I make this work so that if the user expands his screen, you will not be able to see any white space on the top, left, or bottom?

Comment: you have already done this, if you resize jsFiddles result view you can see that the black div changes its size

Comment: Yes - but when I expand the browser size, I am seeing white space on top, left, and bottom. I need this to appear as if the screen is split by a diagonal line with the left side fully black and right side white.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to use an image, but if you find a solution I would like to hear it :)

Comment: I thought I had this solved by just applying position: fixed to everything. But this doesn't work if I want the design to look good on a lower resolution and mobile devices.  I even tried to use an equation with jquery to have the css change based on window widths and heights, but I can't figure out the correlation. Can you expound on your image idea?